# listen tcp :8080: bad file descriptor

Tags: go

Use simple Golang example at MIPS architecture linux device.
Need to start http server at 8080 port (or any another).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    fmt.Printf("Starting server at port 8080\n")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

But got an error like this:

```
Starting server at port 8080
listen tcp :8080: bad file descriptor
```

So server don't start. Any suggestions how to start anyway?

Comment: AFAIK `net` uses `c` standart library (for DNS lookups). Do you have target architecture's C compiler and toolchain while building your binary?

Comment: I building binary on PC with amd64 arch with keys for mipsle arch. So no building at target device - just running.  Any console bins working good.

Comment: Also trying 127.0.0.1:8080 etc.    Looks like another "Golang bad file descriptor" problem with access modes: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR.  But how implement with this case don't know.   Bin running under root.

Comment: Are you using `GOOS` and `GOARCH` flag if you're not building on the target machine? If not, use `GOOS=linux GOARCH=mips go build`. Also read: https://golang.org/doc/install/source#introduction

Comment: I use GOOS and GOARCH for buildiing... And as I say before - simple println examples working good on target device. Need more..